# Transforming a one-column list in a rectangular table in excel

Tags: excel

I have a list in Excel, which is a great number of data, one per row, in a column in Excel. I want to make a rectangular table from it to make it easier to see and print. And I would like to have a method that is able to do it easily, because I keep changing this list and I would have to generate the table everytime I am going to print the file.

For example:
I have in the first column the following data (one per row): 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8

Then, I apply the method I am looking for, in order to have 3 columns. The table will look like:

```
1  2  3

4  5  6

7  8
```

Do you know if there is an automatic way to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can accomplish this task with a simple macro. I tried to arrange some code for you that you can use as reference:

```vb
Sub ReArrangeColumnInRectangularTable()

Dim sourceColumn As Range 'This is the address of first cell in the column to be resized

Dim destinationCell As Range 'This is the first cell address of your rectangular table

Dim size As Integer 'This is the number of columns you wish to use for resizing the original column

'You may want to change the below parameters with others more suitable for you or use an input box
Set sourceColumn = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
Set destinationCell = ActiveSheet.Range("H1")
size = 3

'Selection of all data in the source Column to be used to fill in the rectangular table
'I choosed to make it automatically up to the first empty cell.
'You may alter this part depending your needs
sourceColumn.Select
Set SourceData = sourceColumn.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))

'Process for arranging data in the rectangular table of columns
For i = 1 To SourceData.Rows.Count
    Select Case i Mod size
        Case 0
            destinationCell.Offset((i \ size - 1), (size - 1)).Value = SourceData(i).Value
        Case Else
            destinationCell.Offset(i \ size, (i Mod size) - 1).Value = SourceData(i).Value
    End Select

Next

End Sub
```

You may change some parameters, in order to adapt this macro to your needs. You may also revise part of the code for a different approach to input parameters.

Comment: It looks like there is also a way of converting a vector into a matrix just using formulas. You can find all details following this [link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/VectorToMatrix.aspx).